# upload paperclip attachment to s3 using fog gem for specificaly one model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, fog

I am using fog gem to upload my paperclip attachmets to S3. This is my config file. But it attaches every models attachments to S3. I am trying to implement it on just one model... I couldnt find much documentation of fog with paperclip.

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
          :storage => :fog,
          :fog_credentials => {
            provider: "AWS",
            aws_access_key_id: "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID",
            aws_secret_access_key: "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
          },
          :fog_directory => "BUCKET_NAME"
      }
```

Comment: I was looking for a sample fog config. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this will be to define the storage facilities for each model (I think)

By defining the defaults in the `environment` file, you're going to define those settings for all models. You can use this code for each model:

---

```
#app/models/your_model.rb
:styles => { :medium => "x300", :thumb => "x100" },
        :default_url => "your_url",
        :storage => :s3,
        :bucket => '******',
        :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS

#config/initializers/s3.rb
S3_CREDENTIALS = { :access_key_id => ENV['S3_KEY'], :secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET']}
```

I appreciate this is not DRY, but it should help resolve your issue. Just take the code from your `environment` files & put into your `models`

Comment: Hey Rich Peck i think this might be the solution but then how would i keep my development and production bucket different.

Comment: I think you can define using the tutorial here: http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/master/Paperclip/Storage/S3

Comment: You could also read the bucket value from ENV, which would allow you to separate dev/prod.